# Finding point with largest weight within a region

Tags: algorithm, geometry

My problem is:

We have a set of `N` points in a 2D space, each of which has a weight. Given any rectangle region `R`, how to efficiently return the point with the largest weight inside `R`?

Note that all query regions `R` have the same shape, i.e. same lengths and widths. And point and rectangle coordinates are float numbers.

My initial idea is use a `R`-tree to store points. For a region `R`, extract all points in `R`, and then find the point with max. weights. The time complexity is `O(logN + V)`, where `V` is number of points in `R`. Can we do better?

I tried to search the solution, but still not successfully. Any suggestion?

Thanks,

Comment: Would a [quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) help perhaps?

Comment: If the weights of the points inside R are randomly distributed, then you have to check each point inside the rectangle.  By the way, do you want an algorithm for checking or an implementation?  SO is mainly a coding resource.

Comment: what kind of search did you try so far? i think a "sweep-line" algorithm might work here

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a range max query problem in 2D. You have some very good algorithms [here](https://www.imsc.res.in/~dsmeet/rangemax.pdf).

Simpler would be to just use a 2D [segment tree](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/segment-tree-set-1-range-minimum-query/).

Basically, each node of your segment tree will store 2d regions instead of 1d intervals. So each node will have 4 children, reducing to a quad tree, which you can then operate on as you would a classic segment tree. This is described in detail [here](http://kaidul.com/2d-segment-quad-tree-problem-solving/).

This will be `O(log n)` per query, where `n` is the total number of points. And it also allows you to do a lot more operations, such as update a point's weight, update a region's weights etc.

Comment: @ IVlad : Does it work if coordinates are float, not integer numbers?

Comment: @user2210078 it should be possible to adapt it to work in that case as well. For example, if you have `n` points, normalize them so their coordinates are integers in `[1, n]`. For points `1.4, 3.4, 5.6`, you'd sort them and replace them with their index in sorted order, resulting in `1, 2, 3`. For an `x, y` query, you'd find the `x, y` position in this sorted order as well. For the above, a `2.5, 5` query would result in a `2, 2` query. I think this should work for 2d as well. I'm not aware of an algorithm that handles floats by its nature.

Comment: If you can afford the memory increase, you could also multiply all of your coordinates by 10 to the power of however many decimal places you care about, and then you'll have integer coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding an additional attribute to each tree node which contains the maximum weight of all the points contained by any of its children.

This will be easy to update while adding points. It'll be a little more work to maintain when you remove a point that changes the maximum. You'll have to traverse the tree backwards and update the max value for all parent nodes.

With this attribute, if you want to retrieve the maximum-weight point then when you query the tree with your query region you only inspect the child node with the maximum weight as you traverse the tree. Note, you may have more than one point with the same maximum weight so you may have more than one child node to inspect.

Only inspecting the child nodes with a maximum weight attribute will improve your query throughput at the expense of more memory and slower time building/modifying the tree.

Answer (score 0):

Look up so called range trees, which in your case you would want to implement in 2-dimensions. This would be a 2-layer "tree of trees", where you first split the set of points based on x-coordinate and then for each set of x-points at one of the nodes in the resulting tree, you build a tree based on y-coordinate for those points at that node in the original tree. You can look up how to adapt a 2-d range tree to return the number of points in the query rectangle in O((log n)^2) time, independent of the number of points. Similarly, instead of storing the count of points for subrectangles in the range tree, you can store the maximum objective value of points within that rectangle. This will give you O(n log n) time guaranteed storage and construction time, and O((log n)^2) query time, regardless of the number of points in the query rectangle.

An adaptation of so-called "fractional cascading" for range-tree "find all points in query rectangle" might even be able to get your query time down to O(log n), but I'm not sure since you are taking max of value of points within the query rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Every point has a "zone of influence", which is the locus of the positions of the (top-left corner of the) rectangle such that this point dominates. The set of the zones of influence defines a partition of the plane. Every edge of the partition occurs at the abcissa [ordinate] of a given point or its abscissa [ordinate] minus the width [height] of the query region.

If you map the coordinate values to their rank (by sorting on both axis), you can represent the partition as a digital image of size `4N²`. To precompute this image, initialize it with minus infinity, and for every point you fill its zone of influence with its weight, taking the maximum. If the query window size is `R²` pixels on average, the cost of constructing the image is `NR²`.

A query is made by finding the row and column of the relevant pixel and returning the pixel value. This takes two dichotomic searches, in time `Lg(N)`.

This approach is only realistic for moderate values of `N` (say up to `1000`). Better insight can be gained on this problem by studying the geometry of the partition map.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a weighted voronoi-diagram when the positive weight is substracted from the euklidian distance. Sites with big weight tends to have big cells with near-by sites with small weights. Then sort the cells by the number of sites and compute a minimum bounding box for each cell. Match it with the rectangular search box.